# How to use S3 Select for Nested Parquet Objects

Tags: python, amazon-s3, parquet, amazon-s3-select

I have dumped data into a parquet file.
When I use

> SELECT * FROM s3object s LIMIT 1

it gives me the following result.

```
 {
    "name": "John",
    "age": "45",
    "country": "USA",
    "experience": [{
            "company": {
                "name": "ABC",
                "years": "10",
                "position": "Manager"
            }
        },
        {
            "company": {
                "name": "BBC",
                "years": "2",
                "position": "Assistant"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to filter the result where company.name = "ABC"
so, the output should be looks like following.

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": "45",
    "country": "USA",
    "experience": [{
            "company": {
                "name": "ABC",
                "years": "10",
                "position": "Manager"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

or this

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": "45",
    "country": "USA",
    "experience.company.name": "ABC",
    "experience.company.years": "10",
    "experience.company.position": "Manager"
}
```

Any support is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: have you tried Boto3?

Comment: how about `SELECT * FROM s3object AS s WHERE s.experience.company.name = "ABC"` ?

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I used the S3 GUI to run the sql query. If I can get the result hope to use it in boto3. I tried s.experience.company.name = ‘ABC’. But it did not show any result.

Comment: S3 Select supposedly supports PartiQL so it might be possible to write this using an EXISTS subquery, similar to the example in https://partiql.org/tutorial.html#use-case-checking-whether-a-nested-collection-satisfies-a-condition

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how should I apply PartiQL to the above query?